# How to process a large image in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a machine learning problem on Keras. My objective is to train a model whose input is a `(4214, 22311)` matrix and output is `(22311,)` vector.

Such a two dimensional data can be treated as an image input, but most of image classifiers only work with the small image with shape `(200, 200)`, for example.

I tried several way to build a model on Keras, such as CNN, Bidirectional LSTM, or a simple neural network (flatten and dense). But none of them works.

I received `killed` without completing one epoch. So I am wondering what kind of structure can handle such large input.

[image]

Comment: The actual input is shape of `(4214,1)`, but I concatenate some fixed data to transform `(4214,1)` to `(4214, 22312)`. Equivalently, we can treat the input shape as `(4214, 22312)`

Comment: 2 trillion params??? Whoa. The best chances are fully convolutional models with `GlobalMaxPooling`, or maybe a stateful LSTM model.

Comment: Question: aren't the 4214 items independent? I thought (by your previous question) that they were individual samples.

Comment: Also, the fact that all the 22311 items are exactly the same in all of the 4214 rows makes me think a lot about whether this would be the best approach....

Comment: One data sample is described by 4214 features, so we have a 4214 entries of input. Assume they are independent. And yes, in my last question other 22311 items are the same of the 4214 rows, so apart from using CNN what other methods do you think might work?

Comment: Can you share what you're doing? What this data means? What do the results mean? It seems there should be a better way of doing this....

Comment: I am studying a graph. Each node in the graph is described by a feature vector with shape of 4214 dimensions. I want to learn the pattern how a node connects others; in other words, I want to design a model taking node features and graph structure into account. So I input feature vector to the model along with feature matrix including all nodes in the training set. I am using connection information as the label, which means how the input node connects to all nodes in the training set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance that it could work in a fully convolutional model where you must eliminate the spatial dimensions before any kind of flatten/dense. But since there would be way too many convolutions with just identical data, it seems quite not the best idea....

And since you want an output with 22311 results, probably the LSTM approach (considering the one different variable is the first one) will be the most useful....

**An LSTM model:**

At a first attempt, you could try a non stateful LSTM model.

But do not work as if the last dimensions were features (20000 features will create way to many parameters)!!! Work as if they were time steps instead.

Transforming features in steps may make it more difficult for the model to get an understanding. On the other hand, if you don't, your memory will always blow up. But if the one different data is the first step, there's a good chance that all the following (and repeated) data gets some additional meaning.

So, first, we're reshaping to only one feature:

```
inp = Input((4214,1))
out = Lambda(yourFunction, output_shape=(4214,22312))(inp)
out = Reshape((4214,22312,1))(out)
```

And now, let's try a trick to make it as if it was a sequence of sequences, adding the TimeDistributed wrapper (this allows a dimension increase):

```
out = TimeDistributed(LSTM(cells,return_sequences=True))(out)

#you may add more
```

Let's keep `return_sequences = True`, because you want a very similar number of steps at the end of your model.

At some point, let's collapse the 4214 dimension, placing it at the end, as if it were the time steps (or even as if it were features - risky, but a lot less risky than 23312 features). Here, since they're independent, a `Bidirectional` wrapper might come in handy:

```
out = Permute((2,1,3))(out)
```

1 - if you opt by the 4214 steps:

```
#you can use one or more layers with return_sequences=True before this one
out = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(cells,return_sequences=False)))(out)
```

2 - if you opt by the 4214 features:

```
#remove the last dimension which was 1
out = Reshape((22312,4214))  

#no need to care about they being a sequence, no TimeDistributed, no Bidirectional. 
out = LSTM(cells,return_sequences=True)(out)
    #the return_sequences=True here relates to the 22312 steps   

#but you need to go back to 1 feature per step:
out = Reshape((22312,1))(out)
```

Now the 4214 dimension has collapsed, everything is now a sequence shaped like `(batchSize, 22312, 1)`. Since we're not 4D anymore, but 3D, we can abandon the TimeDistributed wrapper:

```
out = LSTM(cells,return_sequences=True)(out)
```

At the end, use a lambda layer to discard the first element of this sequence (just to match your desired output):

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:,:], output_shape=(22311,1))(out)
out = Reshape((22311,))(out)

model = Model(inp,out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your model, but I don't know what proper value I could choose for `cells`. I received error `ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.` The error happens at the `out = TimeDistributed(LSTM(cells,return_sequences=True))(out)`. And currently I set cells `22312` except the last one, which is `22311`.

Comment: I create a [github repo](https://github.com/wedoso/GraphNeuralNetwork). It would be great if you could check my code for details.

Comment: Oh, you used nsamples as the number of cells. This will cause a very huge weight matrix again. The number is not exact, you can test for the numbers that perform best. But think of things about 50, 100. If you reach 10000 you're probably way beyound what is really necessary.

Comment: Okay.. So the next error happens at `out = Permute((2,1))(out)`, which is `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer permute_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: Okay, it runs... But `ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[94022768,50]` ( I am choosing `cells=50`). Basically, now we have `81,000` params. Am I going to adjust `cells` to smaller value? Like `10`? Or it won't help?

Comment: GPU? I faced that problem a few days ago.... and I haven't solved it yet. It seems the GPU memory is small compared to the CPU memory. You can try smaller values indeed, but maybe you should use CPU instead. (Considering that GPUs aren't really good for LSTM layers: http://minimaxir.com/2017/07/cpu-or-gpu/)

Comment: Thanks. On GPU, I tried `cells=10`, and it still doesn't work. So I switch to CPU, by using `with tf.device('/cpu:0')`. The training speed is VERY SLOW